# How to overwrite Highcharts credits default settings

Tags: python, html, django, highcharts

I've been trying to customize the settings of the credits on a Highchart but without success. I'm working on Django, passing data from Python to my html file in which the Highchart object is rendered, everything works except for the credits settings.

See my code below:

```
    <div id={{ chartID|safe }} class="chart">
    </div>

    <!-- Maps the Python template context variables from views.py to the Highchart js variables -->

    <script>
        var chart_id = "#chart_ID"
        var chart = {{ chart|safe }}
        var title = {{ title|safe }}
        var xAxis = {{ xAxis|safe }}
        var yAxis = {{ yAxis|safe }}
        var series = {{ series|safe }}
    </script>

    <!-- Highchart js. Variable map shown above -->

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(chart_id).highcharts({
            chart: chart,
            title: title,
            xAxis: xAxis,
            yAxis: yAxis,
            series: series,
            plotOptions: {series: {borderColor: '#303030',allowPointSelect: true,cursor: 'pointer'}},
            credits: {text: 'MyCompanyName',href:'mywebsite.com',color:'#303030',position:{align:'center',verticalAlign:'center'}}
            });
          });
    </script>
```

With the above code, everything shows up nicely when I run it, even the **plotOptions** settings work ... but the credits update doesn't work. Credits still show the default settings, i.e. *highcharts.com* is shown at the bottom right corner of the graph and it doesn't update with my new settings.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: I had the same issue when working with .NET and highcharts. For me the problem was sending the values from .NET to javascript, and for some reason it would not work unless I set the values directly in the javascript file. That said, I copied your credit string and pasted to a random [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/yr8k4vkq/), other than having the credits in the middle of the chart (align and vertical align to center) it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 errors `color` must be inside `style` and `verticalAlign` values are bottom, middle and top so your credits should be like this :

```
credits: {
    text: 'MyCompanyName',
    href:'mywebsite.com',
    position:{
        align:'center',
        verticalAlign:'middle'
    },
    style:{
        color:'#303030'
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jj2uda5o/)